# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Invalid JSON payload received error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Got this error when trying to deploy the Firebase Functions sample code:

```
functions: HTTP Error: 400, Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "gcs_url" at 'function': Cannot find field.
```

There was a "config file missing error" and I added my config.json with Firebase credentials. The `gcs_url` was not used in my code.

Comment: What version of the `firebase-functions` SDK and Firebase CLI are you using? Make sure to update both to the latest version. If that doesn't work, can you run `firebase deploy --debug` and see if that has any more info?

Comment: Updated firebase-tools to lastest version solve the problem. Thanks!